# How to use wordpress for customizing elements?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I would like to make my 4 divs that contains an icon image and some descriptional text to be editable with wordpress. I know how to setup the basics and use widgets like in my footer and sidebar.

But I am wondering if that is the right way to make something like mentioned above editable, can someone please enlighten me?

```
<div class="box">
<div class="box-icon">
<img alt="Design" src="<?php echo $images; ?>1412393625_Monitor-64.png" />
</div>
<div class="box-text">
<h3 class="box-header">Simpel, effectief design</h3>
<p>Dit is een test service om te laten zien hoe het werkt. Werkt het naar behoren?</p>
</div>
</div>
```

So I want to be able to login to wordpress and edit the text in the divs above

Comment: Generally speaking, you have 3 ways to make your extra content editable. 1) Make it a custom post type 2) make it something stored in theme options 3) put a sidebar there and use custom widgets. So yes, using widgets would work fine.

Comment: And in your opinion, what is best pratice surrounding this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practices depends on the role within the site and while you've only asked about edit-ability, you have answer the following questions:

Where do you want it displayed?
If it shows on multiple pages, should each instance be unique, or should one edit show up on every page which shows these elements?

From your description and what I've seen of these, it's generally a one-off on the home page.  In which case, I would put the code you have above in the TEXT side of the WordPress visual editor and then just style it.  If you put the css for them in both the style.css and the editor-style.css  it should be editable and look like you expect it to in both the editor and on the page.  The CSS might look something like:

```
div.box{
  float: left;
  width: 23%;
  margin: 1%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

You can see it here:  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubwbp07r/).

If this would be something like a call-out above the footer and appear on every page, I would manage it in widgets.  Create four sidebars, called something like subfooter1, subfooter2, subfooter3, subfooter4 and then just put the code for each in a widget contained within each sidebar.  Then call the sidebars from inside your footer.php.  Of course, you'll have to style it all and you won't be able to call the images with that php code with using a plugin.